# How to implement SSO using IdentityServer4 (OAuth2) in Apache Superset?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I have a two web applications developed in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET CORE. Both uses SSO (Single Sign-On) using `IdentityServer4` OAuth2.

Now, my client's new requirement is Data Analytics using `Apache Superset` with SSO. I have researched and read `Apache Superset's` official website regarding this implementation. They redirected to `Flask App Builder` which is used as security layer in Superset.

I read document given in Flask App Builder [documentation page](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#supported-authentication-types). They have given sample for SSO using `Google` or `Facebook` or `Twitter`.

But, here in my case I need to implement custom security management using `IdentityServer4`

Is it possible to implement `Apache Superset` SSO (OAuth2) using `IdentityServer4`?

If yes, anyone share documentation or sample to configure it.

Comment: If it supports OAuth2 (which it does) then the answer is probably yes, you'd just need to provision a client in `identityserver4` and provide the correct configuration to the application.

Comment: @mackie do you have any sample or documentation to "provide the correct configuration to the application"?

Comment: The documentation you link to provides examples for Twitter and Google, you'd just need to substitute your equivalent values into that config. e.g. instead of `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` for the `authorize_url` you would use `https://my.identityserver4.com/connect/authorize` etc.

Comment: @mackie Thanks for your response. Let me try and come back if any thing I need